# 呼び出し元は、メンバ関数がconstであることをどのようにして認識していますか？

Tags: c++

コメントアウト部(２箇所)に注意して、
以下のコードをコンパイルすると、コンパイルエラーが出ます。

```cpp
#include <unordered_set>

struct A{
    int x;
    bool operator==(const A& other) const {
        return x == other.x;
    }
    struct Hash{
        size_t operator()(const A& a) /*const*/{
            return std::hash<int>()(a.x);
        }
    };
};

int main(){
    std::unordered_set<A, A::Hash> set; // compile error
    return 0;
}
```

```
error: no match for call to '(const A::Hash) (const A&)'
  noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))>
```

このコンパイルエラーは一体どのように解釈すればよいのでしょうか。

どのようにして、メンバ関数がconstであるかそうでないかに基づいて、このようにエラーを出すことができるのでしょうか。

Comment: 参考までに、gcc 9.2.0 ではエラーは発生しません(https://wandbox.org/permlink/53qWl0tl1WfcdYm3)。gcc 8.3.0 ではエラーになります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> このコンパイルエラーは一体どのように解釈すればよいのでしょうか。

[C++標準ライブラリ要件](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/hash.requirements)では、ハッシュ関数オブジェクト`h`とキー`k`がconst修飾されていても式`h(k)`でハッシュ計算を行えることを要請しています。
つまり、ハッシュ計算用のクラス`Hash`は`size_t Hash::operator()(const Key&) const`演算子オーバーロードを提供すべきです。

---

> どのようにして、メンバ関数がconstであるかそうでないかに基づいて、このようにエラーを出すことができるのでしょうか。

例えばgcc 8.3.0の[libstdc++-v3](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-8_3_0-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/hashtable.h#L195-L196)ライブラリ実装では、下記static_assert文を用いて静的検査を行っています。

```
static_assert(__is_invocable<const _H1&, const _Key&>{},
     "hash function must be invocable with an argument of key type");
```

条件式[`__is_invocable`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-8_3_0-release/libstdc++-v3/include/std/type_traits#L2611-L2624)`<const _H1&, const _Key&>`を、`std::unordered_set<Value,Hash,Pred,Alloc>`のテンプレートパラメータに置き換えると`__is_invocable<const Hash&, const Value&>`となり、以下の関数オブジェクト呼出しが有効であれば`std::true_type`型となります。

```
const Hash h;
const Key k;
h(k);
```